# What can be done before Content Database is connected?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, upgrade, content-database, configuration

Soon we'll be grading our SharePoint environment in an overnight upgrade... I'm currently prepping our servers to make the transition as painless as possible, but what sort of configuration can be completed prior to importing the content database? Currently we've only got the default `SharePoint_Config` database for Central Admin ready.

The things I've got left that I'm not sure on are:

- Configuring Service Applications / services on the servers
- Configuring outbound email
- Adding farm solutions
- Add other general applications (ie SPD, Infopath, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure following things.

- Service Application are configured properly as per old farm.
- Web application(s) is created, authentication configured, DNS configured, ssl in place (if using) and all other settings are in place.
- Configure the settings i.e outgoing email, antivirus exclusion, service account registration
- deployment of the customization / solutions
- Test the application before performing the actual migration. Test migration will give you all the answer what you are missing or should be done before hand.
- any special settings if you have for your environment.

I would do the full configuration before hand rather wait for last min.

Comment: Thanks! Previously people in my position here have just "Imported database, upgraded database/site collections and waited for users to do the testing for them". Trying to get around that sort of mentality here. Are there any scripts you're aware of for general tests of SP applications?

Comment: that is not good practice at all. No, i am sorry we dont have script for testing...check github may be some guru already have it there